# Get The State of Connected Components in Jest & Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, redux, jestjs

Good day people! Let's say that i have this component Class:

```js
@connect(
  state =>({
    someState: state.oneLevel.response
  })
)
export default class SomeClass extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
  super(props)
  this.state ={
    someState: [],
    isLoading: false,
    isLoaded: false
  }
}
}
```

This component has an async call with superagent

```js
componentDidMount(){
 var url = 'someapi.com/somedatatofetch'
 this.setState({isLoading: true})
 request.get(url)
 .set('some headers 1', 'somevalue')
 .set('some headers 2', 'somevalue')
 .then((success) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        isLoaded: true
      })
 })
}
```

Now I've been assigned to write a unit test for this Component to check whether it has successfully changed its state or not. I'm using Jest as my test framework and enzyme for handling DOM Renderer etc.

```js
describe("Network Functionality", ()=>{
  const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><SomeComponent /><Provider>)
  
  it("Should change the isLoaded state to true", ()=>{
    const expectedState = true
    //mocking with supertest
    return mockApi().get('testapi.com/someroute')
    .set('some-headers1', 'somevalue')
    .set('some-headers2', 'somevalue')
    .then((success) => {
    expect(wrapper.state(isLoaded)).toEqual(expectedState)
    })
  }
})
```

With that code the response is as follows:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'isLoaded' of null`

my question is, is there anyway to get the state using connected components?
I've tried exporting the component as ConnectedComponents and {Components}
and it works flawlessly but I want to use connected components.

Why did I want to use connected components? Because the every components of my applications is built using this scheme and its not feasible to export as ConnectedComponents and {Components} for there is so many components within my applications and it might leads to more problems

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to solve this problem by finding the Node component using 
`wrapper.find('SomeComponent')` if you `console.log()` it, you'll see that it will yields the component nodes along with the states. This is my final code

```js
describe("Network Functionality", ()=>{
  const wrapper = mount(<Provider store={store}><SomeComponent /><Provider>)
  
  it("Should change the isLoaded state to true", ()=>{
    const expectedState = true
    var somecomponent = wrapper.find("SomeComponent")
    //mocking with supertest
    return mockApi().get('testapi.com/someroute')
    .set('some-headers1', 'somevalue')
    .set('some-headers2', 'somevalue')
    .then((success) => {
    expect(somecomponent.getNode().state.isLoaded)toEqual(expectedState)
    
    })
  }
})
```

as you can see I'm making another variable to contain the `SomeComponent` search result. And finally, i called the getNode() function to get the `SomeComponent` along with its states.
I did not know whether this is the best practice or not but it works. I'd love some feedback tho if there's a better way of doing this